# Issues Installing Progress DataDirect

Tags: odbc, salesforce, progress-4gl

I'm attempting to install Progress' DataDirect for Windows 64-bit in order to create an ODBC for Salesforce.com. Each time I attempt to install the software, the installation stalls at 6%. Any idea what might be causing this or how I can get around it to successfully install the program?

Comment: We were informed that the ODBC driver was only 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the installer "As Administrator"? I'm not sure what else might cause that issue and you can contact them [here](https://www.progress.com/data-connectivity/contact) if you need evaluation support.